# How to get the cell value as a currency of excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I set excel sheet one of the the column as a  currency format $ and decimal places 2.
Like $0.00.

But while displaying in datagridview in it showing like :0.0000.
If set currency as none.Then it is showing 0.00. 
If i add $ symbol. it is showing extra digits values.

Can you please help how can i show as it is (mean like:$0.00) only In windows application.

Comment: you have to give a format to your currency datagrid field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give a format to your currency datagrid field. that is, assign to that column a property called `DataFormatString` and value of `{0:c}`

for additional info: check that link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Money" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Money"
                    SortExpression="Money" />
```

Comment: Thanks your reply.I am using windows application.let me know i can i set.

Comment: i used this way : dataGridView1.Columns["Debit"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"; I am still getting 0.000